# How do you program UITextfield so it is only allowed with one decimal? iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, uitextfield, string-formatting

So I'm programming the textfield so that it only shows $X,XXX.XX. The format I already got working, it's just that I don't want the user to type in things like xxx.xx.xxx.

I only want there to be two more digits after the decimal and then not allow them to type anymore. How can I implement this?

Comment: This is a duplicate of your 1st question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22308313/how-can-i-disable-the-decimal-key-on-ios-keyboard. Why are you asking it again?

Answer (score 2):

You implement the `UITextFieldDelegate` method

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField 
    shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range 
                replacementString:(NSString *)string
```

and return NO for anything that you don't want to allow.

Comment: @user3178926 Note that you can preview the proposed new string with a line of code like this `NSString *newString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];` Then return YES if the new string is satisfactory.

Comment: thank you! do you happen to know if I can detect what character got backspaced/deleted? (as the user edits)

Comment: Well, if the replacement string is empty or nil, and the range is not, then that range should be deleted I guess.